# How to loop through string and remove specific elements?

Tags: java, arrays, filtering

So if I have this: 'my message that needs checking'.

And I have a string with this: `[1][3][4]`. These are the elements of the message that I want to remove (e.g. 'my' would be element 1, 'that' would be element 3).

How would I loop through this message and remove the elements in this other string?

Example:

```
String messageToFilter = "my message that needs checking";
String filter = "[1]-[3]-[4]";

for (String curElement : filter.split("-")) {
    //If I remove element [0], element [3] is then moved to [2]; so not sure what to do!
}

//So at this stage I need the messageToFilter, but with the elements from filter removed.
//In the example above this would output 'message checking'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop backwards over the array of items to remove

```
String[] toFilter = filter.split("-");
for ( int i = toFilter.length() - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
    ///remove the items
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the *indexes* from the `filter` as integers, and then remove the words at this position in the sentence.

```
    String messageToFilter = "my message that needs checking";
    // Split into an array of words
    String[] words = messageToFilter.split("\\s+");

    // get the indexes
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher("[1]-[3]-[4]");
    while (mat.find()) {
        int index = Integer.parseInt(mat.group());
        // set the matching word to null (assuming the indexes start at 1)
        words[index-1] = null;
    }
    // Rebuild the message
    StringBuilder messageFiltered = new StringBuilder();
    for (String w : words) {
        if (w != null) {
            messageFiltered.append(w).append(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(messageFiltered.toString());
```

Output:

> message checking

Answer (score 0):

I propose you create a second string (or List) as your result.

```
String messageToFilter = "my message that needs checking";
String filter = "[1]-[3]-[4]";
String result = null;
for (String curElement : filter.split("-")) {
   if(curElement.equalsIgnoreCase("[3]")) {
       result = curElement;
       break; // or whatever you need to do with the result.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try :

```
public static void main(String[] argss){

   String messageToFilter = "my message that needs checking";
   String filter = "[1]-[3]-[4]";
   ArrayList<Integer> lst=new ArrayList<Integer>();
   String[] fltr = filter.split("-");

   for (String curElement : fltr) {
       // populate lst with indexes to filter !
       lst.add(Character.getNumericValue(curElement.charAt(1)));
   }

   String result="";
   String[] msgSplitted=messageToFilter.split(" ");

   for(int i=0; i<msgSplitted.length;i++){
       if(!lst.contains(i+1))
       {
           //Checks if this index i must be flitered
           //Otherwise, add matching word to result
           result=result+" "+msgSplitted[i];
       }
   }
   System.out.print(result); //your result
}
```

Comment: Still, you would get `1` for the first number, while after you split the message, "my" would be at 0 index. You would have to decrement all numbervalues with 1. I don't see that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looping backwards and replacing the indexes with space, then construct a new String without space.

```
    String filterString = "[1]-[3]-[4]";

    String messageToFilter = "my message that needs checking";

    String[] words = messageToFilter.split("\\s");// filterString for white space

    String[] indexes = StringUtils.split(filterString, "]|\\[|-");// filterString the numbers out

    for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        for (int j = indexes.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

            if (i > j)
                break;

            if (i == j) {
                int valueAtIndex = Integer.parseInt(indexes[i]);
                words[valueAtIndex-1] = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer();
    for (String word : words) {
        if(word!="")
            bf.append(word).append(" ");
    }

    System.out.println(bf.toString());
```